# Scroll with undamaged border-radius

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my client.

He is a famous designer and cannot believe that it's not possible to keep undamaged border with `border-radius` and `overflow: scroll`.

Could someone explain to him?

```css
.example{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px ridge gold;
    border-radius: 14px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='example'></div>
```

Comment: What is an "undamaged border"?

Comment: @amn, gold border 2px on top right and bottom right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align the scrollbar to the border radius, you have to **style** the **scrollbar**.

#### Example

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 14px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 14px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='example'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, delectus eligendi ipsa harum, sunt reprehenderit aliquid, debitis consequuntur minus, ratione odit esse ullam expedita eveniet! Sint iure in blanditiis, accusamus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  width: 105px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.example div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 2px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='example'>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**
Try box-shadow for creating the border type feeling around the scrollbar

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 14px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px gold, 4px -3px gold, -3px 2px gold, -2px -2px gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='example'>

</div>
```